# How do i access to the HTML element inside PHP?

Tags: php, html, dom

For example i have an element `<p>` with the attribute **id="targetParagraph"** inside the `<body>` of an HTML document, how can i access that `<p>` element from PHP code ?

Comment: PHP is not Javascript. PHP runs server-side, it generates your HTML, it doesn't access it. See: [Difference between Server Side Scripting and Client Side Scripting](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-server-side-scripting-and-client-side-scripting/).

Comment: Are you trying to process HTML you have scraped from a page?

Comment: @RiggsFolly no, i'm not scraping HTML, i am on a PHP file, that has the function to verify if the user's account has already existed in the csv text file. And what i want to do, is that if the php function detected an existed account, it will send out an error

Answer (score 0):

## Php DOM parser

**Example 1**

```
// Get the html 
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load("index.html");
$div = $dom->getElementById('totaal');
print_r($div); //prints everything it gets
```

**Example 2**

```
<?php
$htmlEle = "<p id='paraID'>Paragraph Sports</span>";
$domdoc = new DOMDocument();
$domdoc->loadHTML($htmlEle);
 
//echo $domdoc->getElementById('paraID')->nodeValue;
echo $domdoc->getElementsByTagName('paraID');
```

1. Using the PHP DOMDocument Class, call the DOMDocument object.
2. Call the predefined loadHTML() function with variable parameters.
3. Using the getElementById() DOM function we get the HTML element value.

## Using strpos and substr

Assuming the content to extract the paragraph from is in the variable $html (which may have come from a file, database, template or downloaded from an external website), use the following code to work out the position of the first

tag, the first

tag after that tag, and then get all the HTML between them including the opening and closing tags:

```
$start = strpos($html, '<p>');
$end = strpos($html, '</p>', $start);
$paragraph = substr($html, $start, $end-$start+4);
```

`Line 1` gets the position of the first opening `<p>` tag.

`Line 2` gets the position of the first `</p>` after the first opening `<p>`

`Line 3` then uses `substr` to get the HTML. The third parameter is the number of characters to copy and is calculated by subtracting `$start` from `$end` and adding on the length of `</p>` so it is included in the extracted HTML.

**Converting to plain text**

If the extracted paragraph needs to be in plain text rather than HTML, use the following to remove the HTML tags and convert HTML entities into normal plain text:

```
$paragraph = html_entity_decode(strip_tags($paragraph));
```

For more explanation check [The DOMDocument Class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: Thank you for your comments, it's very detailed. However, i can work with the example 2 of the Php DOM parser and change my code abit, but it still result in an error.
Error name: PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "nodeValue" on null
This is my html doc
<main>
    <p id="testingText">this is a testing Text</p>
  </main>

and this is my php code: <?php
      // Get the html
      $dom = new DOMDocument();
      $dom->loadHTML("../php/access.php");
      // Enable validate on parse
      echo $dom->getElementById('testingText')->nodeValue;
      ?>

Comment: Change `echo $domdoc->getElementById('paraID')->nodeValue;`
    with `echo $domdoc->getElementsByTagName('paraID');` as I have updated in the answer and tell me if you have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use JavaScript within PHP?
For example:

```
echo '<script>document.getElementById("targetParagraph").innerHTML="An error occured!";</script>';
```

Answer (score -2):

Well PHP is a server side language. It can't access php.